# Angular UI Grid Demo bug

Tags: angularjs, grid, ui-grid

Learning Angular UI Grid, believe the [official tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro) has a bug.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55t1a.jpg)

Here is my code, local.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/ui-grid.css"></script>

    <style>
        .grid {  width: 500px;  height: 250px;}
    </style>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.myData = [
              {
                  "firstName": "Cox",
                  "lastName": "Carney",
                  "company": "Enormo",
                  "employed": true
              },
              {
                  "firstName": "Lorraine",
                  "lastName": "Wise",
                  "company": "Comveyer",
                  "employed": false
              },
              {
                  "firstName": "Nancy",
                  "lastName": "Waters",
                  "company": "Fuelton",
                  "employed": false
              }
            ];
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using VS 2015 Community. ui-grid.js is the latest ui-grid - v3.2.9 - 2016-09-21, installed by NuGet. 
I originally tested in another big project, to test if other code/files interfe the behavivor, I created a new simple web project just to test this, also moved the content of data .js file into .html above.
Verified no jQuery files required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should be  tag rather than  tag, it caused the .css is not loaded:

```
<script src="/Content/ui-grid.css"></script>
```

Comment: Should be **<Link>** tag.

Comment: Thanks. It was easy to overlook that bug. Changing <script src="/release/ui-grid.css"></script> to <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" /> fixed the bug and displayed the grid as expected.